# Jmeter remote testing hangs and throughput drops significantly

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, distributed

I have set up Jmeter 4.0 in Google cloud where a master talks to 12 slaves for load generation. For really low number of threads, the test works like a charm with the report being generated at the end.

However, when I increase the # threads per slave host to over 200, the test seems to hang and I do not see many requests on the server side. After the ramp up period, I do not see the activity being sustained for over 5 min and it trickles there after. I can verify with the DB counts - the rate drops a lot after the ramp up ends. At the end of the 30 min test, only some hosts seem to shut down and end the test gracefully while there is no info about the others. The java proc on the master keeps running even after 2 hours but not doing anything, i.e. 0 activity.

Has anyone seen an issue with remote testing and report generation?

Comment: Yes.  I moved to an alternate approach at larger scale.  I run all my tests standalone on each server, gather reports, do a combine on the reports, and use command line tool to generate the report.

Comment: Are your reports correct? In my case, I noticed 0 errors in the raw csv file and yet the report generated has majority KOs, doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Jai,

I would suggest to troubleshoot this issue with below steps:

- Check the CPU/Memory utilization in Master and Slave nodes when you run the test
- Increase the heap size in JMeter.bat file in Master and Slave nodes
- Run your test in [non-gui](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) mode using below command:
  jmeter -n -t script.jmx -R server1,server2,... -l Path\To\scriptresults.jtl

n to start Jmeter in a non-gui mode
t to define the jmeter file
r to start the remote server as defined in the JMeter properties file 
R to define the list of servers and start them

Comment: I am already using the Google cloud (read 1st line), all machines have 8GB RAM and 30GB disk. The machines are hardly ever stressed. I am obviously using the command line to run the tests. They run fine for few threads per slave but not with 200. I am using the Concurrency Thread group from BlazeMeter, wondering if that freezes at scale?

Comment: Have not seen issues with those plugins at scale, they are meant for that.  The issues I see are as Ravi calls out, I needed to update my Memory parameters.  Perhaps -Xmx6G in your case.